# Can WPF application adjusted dynamically based on the System Resolution

Tags: wpf

Could you please tell me , can I create WPF application with dynamic system resolution. Here I mean that based on the System Resolution my WPF application need to be adjusted automatically.

Right now, I am implementing WPF application with fixed Width and Height.

Please provide your suggestions....

Thanks,

Sukesh.

Comment: define "adjust automatically"

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess on what you are talking about here.

You can determine your system resolution using:

```
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

From there you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Actually we are doing UI screens for WPF application on Laptop But we are planing to give demo on 22"inch Monitor. Here Dimensions are getting changed when we see UI screens on 22"inch Monitor. How can I make same UI screen apperance on both Laptop and 22" inch Monitor? please help me here....

Comment: Are the resolutions the same? If not, by same do you mean how much of the screen it fills?